# Chrome is calling the route which returns mp3 file twice

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express

My route takes a sentence and returns the `.mp3` file of it:

```
app.get('/audio/:sentence', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log('called HERE')

    let path = '../audios/' + req.params.sentence + '.mp3'

    let stat = fs.statSync(path)

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/x-wav',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    })

    return fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)

})
```

and when I type `http://localhost/audio/welcome`, express logs:

```
called HERE
GET /audio/welcome 200 6.183 ms - 31724
called HERE
GET /audio/welcome 200 0.956 ms - 31724
```

Needless to say, if I insert `res.end` anywhere before `res.writeHead` the route is only executed once, as expected.

Comment: There has to be more to this story than you are showing here.  This route does not call itself.  So, it's apparently something that the caller is doing that causes it to call the route a second time or perhaps some middleware that's doing something odd.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh, I just realized this is Chrome's doing. If I do an actual 'GET' from bash it's only executed once and Firefox downloads the file (again invoked once). Any clue why Chrome is calling this route twice?

Comment: How are you calling the route?  Are you using the URL in an embedded audio player?  Or are you typing the URL into the browser.  If you're typing it into the browser, it appears that the browser is expecting these types `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3` and you're giving it `audio/x-wav` which apparently causes it to request data again with `Accept: */*`.

Comment: I believe Chrome has done something for security reasons that causes it to ignore Content-Type values that are not what it asked for.  If you look in the Network tab of the Chrome debugger, you can see the two requests and see the difference in the Request Headers (that's what I did).

Comment: Perfect. This is it @jfriend00. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you calling the route? Are you using the URL in an embedded audio player? Or are you typing the URL into the browser.

If you're typing it into the browser, it appears that the Chrome is expecting these types

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
```

and you're giving it `audio/x-wav` which apparently causes it to request data again with

```
Accept: */*
```

I believe Chrome has done something for security reasons that causes it to ignore Content-Type values that are not what it asked for. If you look in the Network tab of the Chrome debugger, you can see the two requests and see the difference in the Request Headers (that's what I did).